# Remesh destroys separation between fingers

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I would like to do a final Remesh for my model after sculpting out the hands but using Remesh even with a Voxel size as small as 0.005 merges the gaps between the fingers. How can I avoid this?

**Hand before Remesh**

[image]

**Hand after Remesh**
[image]

Comment: Have you measured the distance between the fingers? If it is lower than 0.005 the voxel remesh is going to result in artefacts like that. You could try using the Quad remesher to remesh the object depending on how you want to use it later.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/retopology.html

Comment: What do you want to achieve by remeshing?

Comment: @Leander I want to have a clean and even topology before moving on to UV Mapping and such things. I was under the impression that this is part of the workflow finishing up a model. :)
But I admit, it might not be necessary. The different face shapes on the hand dont matter when the model is shaded smooth and I will have to decimate the model later anyway to make it more lightweight for Unity.

Comment: @adegner Thank you, I will give it a try!